# CodeIgniter A PHP Error was encountered fatal eror

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a novice experiencing obstacles in doing the task
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$db
>
> Filename: views/templateadmin.php
>
> Line Number: 311
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\application\views\templateadmin.php
>   Line: 311 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\application\controllers\demo.php Line: 6
>   Function: view
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\website\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

and

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_where() on a non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\website\application\views\templateadmin.php on line
>   311 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function get_where() on a non-object
>
> Filename: views/templateadmin.php
>
> Line Number: 311
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: load database either with autoload.php or in controller's construct

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: I have created a database table where I need to store the database?

Comment: read [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/examples.html)

Comment: please, read the docs: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html

Comment: $autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); in autoload.php

Comment: i want to convert the static website to dynamic with the data base table but i do not have the complete tutorial

Comment: you should first read the ci documentation for that : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: you have to configure then load the database then start to write the queries

Comment: can you tell me step by step. i need help on this

Comment: read the documentation. It's complete and understandable for all levels. They have examples too.

Comment: You have not loaded the database

Comment: @Mr.ED I have created a database in phpmyadmin how to be able to connect with CodeIgniter

Comment: @hungrykoala do you have a tutorial that is easy to understand in brief

Answer (score 1):

write this in your controller

```
$this->load->database();
```

OR
In your application>config>autoload.php file
make sure you have databse written in your libraries

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');
```